# XSLT 1.0 to sort and group an XML

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping

I need an XSLT 1.0 that converts the following XML.

```
<Record>
  <Row>
    <Name>AAA</Name>
    <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>BBB</Name>
    <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>CCC</Name>
    <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>DDD</Name>
    <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>EEE</Name>
    <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>FFF</Name>
    <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>GGG</Name>
    <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Name>HHH</Name>
    <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
  </Row>
</Record>
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
<Output>
  <Recordset1>
    <Record>
      <Name>AAA</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>CCC</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset1>
  <Recordset1>
    <Record>
      <Name>EEE</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>GGG</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset1>
  <Recordset2>
    <Record>
      <Name>BBB</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>DDD</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset2>
  <Recordset2>
    <Record>
      <Name>FFF</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>HHH</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset2>
</Output>
```

The conditions are:

1. Recordset1 should contain Surname1 nodes
2. Recordset2 should contain Surname2 nodes
3. Output should be sorted by Surname
4. There is a maximum of 2 Records per Recordset.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:key match="Row" name="rows" use="Surname"/>

<xsl:template match="Record">
  <Output>
    <xsl:for-each select="Row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('rows', Surname)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="Surname" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>

      <xsl:variable name="Recordset" select="concat('Recordset',position())"/>

      <xsl:variable name="Rows">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('rows', Surname)"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="RowList" select="msxml:node-set($Rows)"/>

      <xsl:for-each select="$RowList/Row[position() mod 2 = 1]">
        <xsl:element name="{$Recordset}">
          <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
          </Record>
          <xsl:if test="following-sibling::Row[1]/*">
            <Record>
              <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::Row[1]/*"/>
            </Record>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </Output>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What on earth do you imagine this does: `<xsl:for-each select="Row[. = key('rows', Surname)[1]]">`?

Comment: This is from the Muenchian method that you kindly pointed out to me previously.  I just simplified the for-each part of it as follows:  For each Row Surname find the first Row instance with that surname.  So, if the current Row is that first instance, then do stuff.  Great question.  BTW, this code works very well.

Comment: "*For each Row Surname find the first Row instance with that surname.*" That's not what your "simplification" does. It finds every Row whose **entire text value** is equal to the text value of the first Row instance with that surname. Which can easily lead to duplicates.

Comment: I added generate-id to the for-each.  There will be no potential problem it. 
Any other suggestions for improvement?

Comment: I didn't read beyond that point. This question was asked in January 2016 and OP hasn't visited for over a year.

Comment: I'm new to this, so I'm not sure what is going on.  It looks like ekad modified the question yesterday.  Does ekad want an answer, or is he just doing some cleanup?

Comment: You can see for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34669229/revisions

Answer (score 0):

There were a few tricks to this:

1. Select distinct surnames.
2. Group the surname records.
3. Subset the surname records in groups of 2.
4. Create dynamic element names based on the distinct surname index.

This stylesheet solves those problems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/Record">
    <Output>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row[not(./Surname=preceding::Surname)]/Surname" mode="group">
        <xsl:sort select="Surname" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Surname" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="surname" select="./text()" />
    <xsl:variable name="surnameIndex" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="surnameGroup" select="/Record/Row[Surname/text()=$surname]" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$surnameGroup">
      <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
      <!-- only create a new record set on the first (or only) member of the output pair -->
      <xsl:if test="$index mod 2=1"> <!-- positions are 1 based, not 0 based -->
        <xsl:element name="Recordset{$surnameIndex}">
          <!-- alternatively, use xsl:copy-of -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$surnameGroup[$index]" mode="record" />
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$surnameGroup[$index+1]" mode="record" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row" mode="record">
    <Record>
      <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></Name>
      <Surname><xsl:value-of select="Surname" /></Surname>
    </Record>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of applying this stylesheet against your input document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Output>
  <Recordset1>
    <Record>
      <Name>AAA</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>CCC</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset1>
  <Recordset1>
    <Record>
      <Name>EEE</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>GGG</Name>
      <Surname>Surname1</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset1>
  <Recordset2>
    <Record>
      <Name>BBB</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>DDD</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset2>
  <Recordset2>
    <Record>
      <Name>FFF</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Name>HHH</Name>
      <Surname>Surname2</Surname>
    </Record>
  </Recordset2>
</Output>
```

Comment: This is not a good answer - see here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're right, its a great answer because it solves the given question while compartmentalizing the different problems @Roland was encountering. If you're concerned about the use of `preceding` being too inefficient for determining the distinct values, then another method could easily be substituted in the first template.